# Solaris old version guest on Windows 7/10(64bit) host using Virtualbox/Vmware

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, solaris

I have very old application(using specific language, CLOS based language) that was installed on a Sun Ultra 10(Solaris 2.6).

I have this OS, application source code with compiler.
I want to know whether it's possible to install this old OS(solaris 2.6) using old builds of VirtualBox, Vmware or others on my current Windows host(windows 7x76 or 10x64).
Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun Ultra 10 uses an UltraSPARC II CPU, and not an x86-family CPU.  So you can't use VirtualBox or VMWare to run Solaris 2.6.

[QEMU](https://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) can be used to emulate SPARC CPUs.  The [UltraSPARC emulation (sun4u) is supported, but in beta](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/SPARC).

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I will review it.